# How can a moving point charge "update" its fields without emitting an e-m wave?

Tags: electromagnetism

If an observer brutally moves a point charge from position A to position B, the electric field produced by the point charge at a given point P changes. Furthermore, a delay is observed before this field changes. My understanding is that an e-m wave (pulse) is emitted when the charge is accelerated and decelerated and that this pulse needs to reach point P before the electric field at P is modified.

Now, what if the point charge moves at a constant velocity and we consider the situation in the reference frame of point P ? How can the electric field be modified if non-accelerating charges don't emit e-m waves ?

I tried many things to get around that paradox. Clearly, if the observer stands in the reference frame of the source charge, only a static electric field is procuded and it's the point P which is moving in that field. But I'd like to read a simple solution in the reference frame of point P.

Comment: Take the constant electric field in the rest system of the charge and apply a relativistic boost to it... that's the time dependent electromagnetic field in the system of a moving observer. Where is the paradox?

Comment: To put @CuriousOne's comment is plainer language: turn the question around. How can an observer move in the field of a stationary charge without the charge emitting EM waves? It's the same question because there is no uniquely identifiable state of rest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I knew that. I even wrote it in my question : see my third paragraph.

Please read my last sentence again : how can it be explained *in the reference frame of point P* ? That's my question.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer ?